# Drupal site being hit with non-sensical requests from redirected page

Tags: redirection

For about a month now, our website has been being bombarded with odd page requests (that I am seeing in dblog).  I'm thinking it might have something to do with a redirect that we've set up, but we're not sure.  We have two domains, let's say www.example.com and www.otherexample.com.  The default page for example.com goes to example.com/drupal, and otherexample.com (being just a catchy name for a certain department) directs back to example.com/drupal/specificdept.  The requests coming in look like someone is attempting to get to pages that exist on the main example.com site, but they're somehow injecting drupal pages onto the end of where otherexample.com redirects.  There is no referrer given, and the requests come from several dozen IPs.

In the dblog I'll have entries like this:

> Page Not Found: www.example.com/drupal/specificdept/robots.txt
>
> Page Not Found: www.example.com/drupal/specificdept/favicon.ico
>
> Page Not Found: www.example.com/drupal/specificdept/drupal/node/260
>
> Page Not Found: www.example.com/drupal/specificdept/drupal/otherdept/info

If I try to navigate to www.otherexample.com/test1, it takes me into example.com/drupal/specificdept/test1, tells me it doesn't exist, and shows no referrer just as the other requests do.  This may be more of a DNS/redirect handling question, but is there a way to prevent someone from doing a crawl on the otherexample domain?  If not, is there a way that regardless of what additional url directories they enter, it will take them back to otherexample.com/specificdept?

Comment: Just to understand it: Did you install Drupal in www.example.com/drupal/specificdept?

Comment: what path/redirect modules do you have enabled on other example.com?

Comment: Drupal is installed in example.com/drupal.  specificdept is just a page within our drupal installation.

Comment: sounds like spambots looking for cracks.  I get calls to wp and joomla directories on occasion as well, and sometimes completely random gibberish

Comment: @longboardnode otherexample.com is not a real site, it just redirects back to our drupal site.  We are only using path on the drupal site.  The redirect is actually being done through Apache.